# Disable font anti aliasing in Firefox in OSX?

Tags: macos, display, font, ui

As much searching and trying I have done, I can not disable text anti aliasing in Firefox.

Can someone please show me a screenshot of Firefox in OSX with no text aliasing. Also, how would I achieve this?

Do I need to edit the Firefox source code and call one the the Apple Quartz apis to disable test anti aliasing?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

- Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced panel -> General tab -> Remove Checkmark from "Use Hardware Acceleration when available"
- Click Ok
- Restart FireFox

Comment: I tried this and the fonts are still anti-aliased.